# Force TLS on mobile app

Tags: tls, android, ios, ajax

i'm developing a mobile application for iOS and Android. On this app i'm asking resources on a secure server through ajax.
Server's developers asked me to force the call in order that we use TLS protocol, i know that i have to specify the usage of it but i don't know how in both platforms.

Here an example of my call with ajax:

```
var urlServizi = 'https://........'
var soapMessage =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                          xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
<soap:Body>\
<Login xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">\
<UserName>AAA</UserName>\
<Password>BBB</Password>\
<lingua>en</lingua>\
</Login>\
</soap:Body>\
</soap:Envelope>';

$.ajax({
       url: urlServizi,
       type: "POST",
       async: true,
       dataType: "text",
       data: soapMessage,
       contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
       success: functionOK,
       error: functionKO
       });
```

Comment: This looks like it does, in fact use TLS. (The URL starts with https://) Have they indicated that there's a problem with this specific code?

Comment: Nono the all function very well, but i'm afraid that when they will use only tls my code does not work.
I'm not sure that the https enough, it does for the usage of tls? If yes i've not problems more.